# Buttons wont work when used with created xml (Android Studio)

Tags: android

I've made a working simple calculator with some bugs here and there, I decided to make all the buttons round by adding the appropriate drawable xml files  to make them round sadly after doing so the buttons now won't work.

**Here is the Main.java**

```
package com.example.calculatorinator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public class txtEvent implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
        }
    }
    Button button0, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, buttonDecimal, buttonClear, buttonDelete, buttonSign, buttonEquals, buttonAdd, buttonSubtract, buttonMultiply, buttonDivide;
    TextView textViewMain, textViewHistory;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    float value1, value2;
    boolean add, subtract, multiply, divide;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button0 = findViewById(R.id.button0);
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button6 = findViewById(R.id.button6);
        button7 = findViewById(R.id.button7);
        button8 = findViewById(R.id.button8);
        button9 = findViewById(R.id.button9);
        buttonDecimal = findViewById(R.id.buttonDecimal);
        buttonClear = findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);
        buttonDelete = findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
        buttonSign = findViewById(R.id.buttonSign);
        buttonAdd = findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        buttonSubtract = findViewById(R.id.buttonSubtract);
        buttonMultiply = findViewById(R.id.buttonMultiply);
        buttonDivide = findViewById(R.id.buttonDivide);
        textViewMain = findViewById(R.id.textViewMain);
        textViewHistory = findViewById(R.id.textViewHistory);
        buttonEquals = findViewById(R.id.buttonEquals);

        button0.setOnClickListener(new button0Event());
        button1.setOnClickListener(new button1Event());
        button2.setOnClickListener(new button2Event());
        button3.setOnClickListener(new button3Event());
        button4.setOnClickListener(new button4Event());
        button5.setOnClickListener(new button5Event());
        button6.setOnClickListener(new button6Event());
        button7.setOnClickListener(new button7Event());
        button8.setOnClickListener(new button8Event());
        button9.setOnClickListener(new button9Event());
        buttonDecimal.setOnClickListener(new buttonDecimalEvent());
        buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new buttonClearEvent());
        buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new buttonDeleteEvent());
        buttonSign.setOnClickListener(new buttonSignEvent());
        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new buttonAddEvent());
        buttonSubtract.setOnClickListener(new buttonSubtractEvent());
        buttonMultiply.setOnClickListener(new buttonMultiplyEvent());
        buttonDivide.setOnClickListener(new buttonDivideEvent());
        buttonEquals.setOnClickListener(new buttonEqualsEvent());
        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new txtEvent());
    }

    private class button0Event implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            textViewMain.setText(textViewMain.getText() + "0");
            textToSpeech.speak(textViewMain.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }

    private class button1Event implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            textViewMain.setText(textViewMain.getText() + "1");
            textToSpeech.speak(textViewMain.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }

    private class button2Event implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            textViewMain.setText(textViewMain.getText() + "2");
            textToSpeech.speak(textViewMain.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }

    private class button3Event implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            textViewMain.setText(textViewMain.getText() + "3");
            textToSpeech.speak(textViewMain.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }

    private class button4Event implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            textViewMain.setText(textViewMain.getText() + "4");
            textToSpeech.speak(textViewMain.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }

    private class button5Event implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            textViewMain.setText(textViewMain.getText() + "5");
            textToSpeech.speak(textViewMain.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }

    private class button6Event implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            textViewMain.setText(textViewMain.getText() + "6");
            textToSpeech.speak(textViewMain.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }

    private class button7Event implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            textViewMain.setText(textViewMain.getText() + "7");
            textToSpeech.speak(textViewMain.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }

    private class button8Event implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            textViewMain.setText(textViewMain.getText() + "8");
            textToSpeech.speak(textViewMain.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }

    private class button9Event implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            textViewMain.setText(textViewMain.getText() + "9");
            textToSpeech.speak(textViewMain.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }

    private class buttonDecimalEvent implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            textViewMain.setText(textViewMain.getText() + ".");
            textToSpeech.speak(textViewMain.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }

    private class buttonClearEvent implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            value1 = 0;
            value2 = 0;
            textViewMain.setText("");
            textViewHistory.setText("");
            textToSpeech.speak("Clear", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }

    private class buttonDeleteEvent implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            String display = textViewMain.getText().toString();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(display)){
                display = display.substring(0, display.length() -1);
            }
            textViewMain.setText(display);
        }
    }

    private class buttonSignEvent implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            textViewMain.setText("-" + textViewMain.getText());
            textToSpeech.speak("Negative" + textViewMain.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }


    private class buttonAddEvent implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(!textViewMain.getText().toString().matches("")){
                value1 = Float.parseFloat(textViewMain.getText() + "");
                add = true;
                textViewHistory.setText(textViewMain.getText() + "+");
                textViewMain.setText("");
                textToSpeech.speak("Plus", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a number first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }

    private class buttonSubtractEvent implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(!textViewMain.getText().toString().matches("")){
                value1 = Float.parseFloat(textViewMain.getText() + "");
                subtract = true;
                textViewHistory.setText(textViewMain.getText() + "-");
                textViewMain.setText("");
                textToSpeech.speak("Minus", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a number first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private class buttonMultiplyEvent implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(!textViewMain.getText().toString().matches("")){
                value1 = Float.parseFloat(textViewMain.getText() + "");
                multiply = true;
                textViewHistory.setText(textViewMain.getText() + "x");
                textViewMain.setText("");
                textToSpeech.speak("Times", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a number first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private class buttonDivideEvent implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(!textViewMain.getText().toString().matches("")){
                value1 = Float.parseFloat(textViewMain.getText() + "");
                divide = true;
                textViewHistory.setText(textViewMain.getText() + "/");
                textViewMain.setText("");
                textToSpeech.speak("Divided by", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a number first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private class buttonEqualsEvent implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            value2 = Float.parseFloat(textViewMain.getText() + "");
            textViewHistory.setText(textViewHistory.getText() + (value2 + ""));

            if(add == true){
                textViewMain.setText(value1 + value2 + "");
                add = false;
            }

            if(subtract == true){
                textViewMain.setText(value1 - value2 + "");
                subtract = false;
            }

            if(multiply == true){
                textViewMain.setText(value1 * value2 + "");
                multiply = false;
            }

            if(divide == true){
                textViewMain.setText(value1 / value2 + "");
                divide = false;
            }

            textViewHistory.setText(textViewHistory.getText() + "=" + (textViewMain.getText() + ""));

            textToSpeech.speak("Equals" + textViewMain.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            value1 = 0;
            value2 = 0;

        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the main xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.calculatorinator.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/Black">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHistory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:padding="35dp"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:padding="35dp"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="665dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMain"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_black"
                android:text="7"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_black"
                android:text="8"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_black"
                android:text="9"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_clear"
                android:shadowColor="#F7E43232"
                android:text="C"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_black"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_black"
                android:text="5"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_black"
                android:text="6"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_orange"
                android:text="÷"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_black"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_black"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_black"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_orange"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonDecimal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_orange"
                android:text="."
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button0"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_black"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonDelete"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_delete"
                android:text="Del"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonSubtract"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_orange"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonSign"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_orange"
                android:text="+/-"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonEquals"
                android:layout_width="108dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_orange"
                android:text="="
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_orange"
                android:text="*"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Added xml files that changes the buttons to circle**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</shape>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>
</shape>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
</shape>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
</shape>
```

I've been trying to find the problem for a while now any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

PS. How do I lessen the number of xml files but still have a variety of round buttons with different colors?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow!  It's great that you included your code in your question.  In the future, it's helpful if you include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  For example, there's a lot of code in here that isn't related to your question (text to speech? 19 buttons when you just need one to show the problem?)

Comment: But, including your code allowed me to copy it into a project and run it.  How are you determining that the buttons aren't working?  For me, I can still hear the number being read when I click the 0 button, for example, and when I add a Log statement to button0Event.onClick() I see it in Logcat.  Is your question perhaps why you don't see the touch state ripple animation on the buttons?

Comment: Hi Michiyo thanks for the feedback next time I would do the minimal reproducible example and also thanks for trying to help but sadly my code is apparently working I just brain farted and was to stupid to realize my mistake. 

Sorry also for not making my question very clear as english is not my native language.

I changed the background color to black while the textview text is also in black font color (yep stupid mistake :D).

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

My calculator was not showing any numbers after pushing the corresponding buttons, I realized the I changed the background color to black while my textView font color was also black, for anyone who was trying to comprehend my question and trying their best to help me I am deeply sorry for wasting your time and thank you.